# Getting Fatal Error in get_results of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['confirm_code'])) {
    __construct();
}

function __construct() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_one = $wpdb->prefix . "fantasticemailnewsletter_temp";

    $confirm = $_GET['confirm_code'];
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->$table_one WHERE confirm_code = $confirm");
    if ($mylink) {
        echo $mylink->confirm_code;
        echo "success";
        echo $wpdb->show_error();
    } else {
        echo "You Subscription is not process right now please try again later";
    }
}

?>
```

I’m trying to create a newsletter plugin in WordPress. I make a confirmation link for the corresponding subscriber to prevent spammers, creating a random key for every subscription e-mail. I pass the random key with query string through mail like this:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugininname/includes/subscriber.php?confirm_code=%2248c9c7d48165379b49f58962c0092466%22
```

In `subscriber.php` only, I’m using the above code, but for some reason, there’s an error at `get_results()`:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object
>   How can I overcome this prob.

Comment: Try adding `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' );` above global $wpdb;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to redeclare wpdb in query `$wpdb->` as you already declared in this line `$table_one = $wpdb->prefix . "fantasticemailnewsletter_temp";`

```
    <?php 
   if(isset($_GET['confirm_code'])) {
__construct();
}
function __construct() {
global $wpdb;

        $confirm = $_GET['confirm_code'];
        $mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}fantasticemailnewsletter_temp WHERE confirm_code = $confirm");
        if($mylink) {
        echo $mylink->confirm_code;
        echo "success";
        echo $wpdb->show_error();
        }
        else {
        echo "You Subscription is not process right now please try again later";
        }
        }
            ?>
```

Comment: ya i changed the $table_one = wp_fantasticemailnewsletter_temp; its getting the same error

Comment: @Vignesh did you use the same code i added here .i tested it already :)

Comment: Hi i pasted the above code and tested here as http://techstumbling.com/wp-content/plugins/fantasticemailnewsletter/includes/subscribe.php?confirm_code=48c9c7d48165379b49f58962c0092466

Comment: Again I added still the same :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30695/discussion-between-santanu-kumar-and-vignesh)

Answer (score 1):

The error looks like the object of wpdb hasn't been instantiated.

Generally a method of a class shall be called after an object has been instantiated, if the method is not a static one. Otherwise this error shows.

I would check other parts of code or the file to see whether it's executed before WP code.

For example, if the file isn't a plugin or a theme (which means the file stands alone) and you haven't properly called WP framework header file before executing this file, the $wpdb object may not have been instantiated. I would definitely try the code by @Rikesh in the comment of your question.

Comment: Thanks @ golddc I am New to this can you provide as sample code if any or link

Comment: I saw @Rikesh 's comment after writing down my answer. You can try the code he provides - I would do the same thing. Then, the following is only for your reference: you can take a look at the index.php under your WP folder, and you'll see it requires wp-blog-header.php . Then go to wp-blog-header.php , and it requires wp-load.php , which is mentioned by Rikesh. This file is loaded before any other files are loaded - you can imagine how important it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->$table_one WHERE confirm_code = $confirm");
$mylink = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Aren't you calling the same function twice here, once with an SQL string, and once (presumably) with a result set?